# Can eclipse automically reduce all package calls to full imports?

Tags: java, eclipse

If I have a class containing calls to `java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger` with full package qualifier - can I somehow tell Eclipse to change these statements to:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

Logger.getLogger...
```

?

Or do I have to manually refactor those classes?
(these full package qualifiers are a result of CXF wsdl auto-generated classes...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the fully qualified classname

```
java.util.logging.Logger
```

then click

```
Source > Add Import
```

(Shortcut: Control + Shift + M)